# How to solve Add to cart not working in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, cart, addtocart

Our "add to cart" button are not working...
When we click on the button, the page refresh then nothing.
Any ideas?

https://stage.shopunder.com

Comment: Hello @Alain Picard I think this issues is Please products section you select  Visibility > Catalog,Search??

Comment: You need to change code